# How to test the max. number of connections of a given TCP port

Tags: linux, networking, performance, tcp, benchmark

We are using a server (closed sourced) written by a vendor that claims it supports up to a maximum of 100 concurrent TCP connections.

We want to test this claim.

We can certainly write a script to automate it, but before that, are there any handy tools we can use to rapidly open 100 TCP connections? Something like `apachebench` to open the TCP connection and close it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with NMAP. See the documentation of parallel connections at:
[NMAP Documentation](http://nmap.org/book/man-performance.html)

Comment: Without an example, that's not a very helpful reference: nmap has a headsplitting number of options available.  Figuring out how to construct a viable command for this purpose is something that even those familiar with nmap may struggle with.

Answer (score 0):

Whip something up using `nc(1)` (part of [nmap](http://nmap.org), that package is probably part of any reputable (and *is* in all disreputable) Linux distribution.